# Is there a Broswer on Ipad capable of "Add a Keyword for this Search" (or Quick Searches) feature?

Tags: ipad, firefox, web-browser

On desktop, Mozilla Firefox has a nice feature to define a smart keyword to enable searching a website through the browser. The details can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar). This feature is sometimes called [Quick Searches](https://lifehacker.com/tag/quick-searches).

On IPad, neither Safari, nor Firefox seem to have this feature.

Is there a browser on IPad, capable of this feature?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the **Cliqz** browser on my iPad and it works well. It has a quick search feature but maybe different from the one you describe. Cliqz is free and available from the app store.

Comment: Thank you for introducing Cliqz. I tested it. It seems that the notion of the "quick searches" in this browser is different from the one I described in my question. Thank you anyway.